# Dart language for a beginner

Tags: dart

I want to install Dart but there is 3 types (Flutter,Web and Dart VM) I just want to execute a simple code just to discover the language but I cant choose between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ to play around with basic language concepts. Dartpad is about to be updated to run Dart 2.x instead of Dart 1.x that is currently used.

It doesn't allow you to add packages from https://pub.dartlang.org which makes it a bit limited.

- For command line apps **and** web apps install the Dart SDK
- For apps that should run on Android or iOS, install Flutter.

So if you don't want to build a mobile app, just install the Dart SDK to be able to utilize all its capabilities without limitations.

It's also perfectly fine to install Dart SDK and Flutter side-by-side, so there isn't really a difficult decision to make.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to learn the language like we're used to with python, Java, or C++, you want Dart VM. It's the part that can be run from the command line. Flutter is for running Dart with GUIs on Android and iOS devices. If you install the other two, you'll get Dart as well. But if you don't want to add all the extra, only install Dart VM.